# MongoDB select distinct where not in select distinct

Tags: mongodb

In a mongoDB bd, I need to find all the records where those records aren't in a different collection

Say I have 2 collections

1) user_autos

```
{
    make: string,
    user_id: objId
}
```

2) auto_makes

```
{
    mfg: string,
    make: string
}
```

I need to find all the "makes" that are not part of the "master makes" list

I want to do the parallel to this SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.make
FROM
    user_autos a
WHERE
    a.make NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        b.make
    FROM
        auto_makes b
    )
```

Help please

Comment: how about seperating into 2 queries. 1. projecting DISTINCT `auto_makes.make` in an array 2. use `nin` +  `group` to project the `a.make`s that is not in the projected array

Comment: Please sharing request and output data at jsoneditor (https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve this, you need to make use of aggragation with pipeline stage 'lookup'.
lookup does left join between two collections. so, obviously the unmatching documents of 
'user_autos' gives an empty nested array 'auto_makes'. and then 'group' the 'user_autos'
with 'make'. so that a list of 'user_auto' documents will be resulted.

you can do it as below.

```
       db.user_autos.aggregate([
        {$lookup:{
          from:"äuto_makes",
          localField:"make",
          foreignField:"make",
          as:"m"
         }},
         {$match:{
          m:{$exists:false}
         }},
         {$group:{
          _id:"$make"
         }}
         //if you want to get the distinct 'make' values as an array of single 
          //document, add another $group stage.
        {$group:{
          _id:"",
          make_list:{$addToSet:"$_id"}
         }}

       ])
```

Visit https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/ ,
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Uma - thx - I will try this shortly and let you know - I knew it would be an aggregate  - but the lookup / match was not in my vocabulary, I appreciate the detail

Comment: small error issue - foriegnField - should be foreignField